# Ruby: Changing the variable outside the method

Tags: ruby, binding, eval

I don't understand how to change variable value from the outside of the method using `binding` and `eval`.
Example method:

```
def foo
  a = 1
  binding
end
```

I can get variable `a` by two ways:

```
foo.local_variable_get(:a) #=> 1
# or
foo.eval("a") #=> 1
```

But I can't set new value

```
foo.local_variable_set(:a, 2)
foo.local_variable_get(:a) #=> still 1
foo.eval("a = 2")
foo.local_variable_get(:a) #=> still 1
```

However, I can do it if Binding object was created in global scope, outside of any method:

```
bar = 123
binding # Binding object with global scope
binding.eval("bar") #=> 123
binding.eval("bar = 456")
binding.eval("bar") #=> 456
```

How can I set new value to method local variable outside the method? Thank you.

Comment: The first question is why do you want to change a local variable inside a method from outside it? Perhaps you don't understand the difference between local, instance, class, and global variables? This sounds like an "[XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/153968)" where you're asking about one thing but really should be asking about another. Explain the goal, why you want to be able to do this in the scope of your program.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. A local variable is used to hold values inside the method that don't need any persistence outside the method. They're destroyed as soon as the method exits. Where would you propose to have that change take place inside a method? At initialization of the local? Mid-stream in some random or arbitrary spot? I'd recommend showing us a code snippet showing how you envision using such functionality.

Comment: @theTinMan, I was reading about this [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Binding.html#local_variable_set-method) and tried similar example in irb. I just want to understand it.

Comment: Did you notice that the use of `local_variable_set` and `local_variable_get` occurs _inside_ the method, not outside it? `b.local_variable_set(:a, 2)` is a long-winded way of saying `a = 2`. Using those methods makes it possible to have Ruby execute code dynamically, on the fly, without there being any source code for it.

Comment: @theTinMan, yes, of course. But when I add method from those example to irb and after that tried to call it, it caused an error "NoMethodError: undefined method local_variable_get for 3:Fixnum", so I suppose there is mistake with variable `b`. Then I was trying to manipulate with variables outside of method and found out that I can't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example you always create new binding (context) by calling `foo`. That is why changes are lost.

It should work if you call the same binding

```
b = foo
b.local_variable_get(:a) # => 1

eval("a = 2", b)
b.local_variable_get(:a) # => 2

b.local_variable_set(:a, 3)
b.local_variable_get(:a) # => 3
```